# Genuino 101 does not run when BLECharacteristic defined

Tags: c++, c, arduino

For an application I'm developing we're working with the Genuino 101.
Because the BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic is too small, I decided to go for the BLECharacteristic.

However the sketch doesn't run when I change it over

```
#ifdef _BLE_
BLECharacteristic data("9ff91ff6-e874-4ff6-8cff-83daaf9d7fc1", BLERead |BLEWrite, RD_BUF_LEN);
#else
BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic data("9ff91ff6-e874-4ff6-8cff-83daaf9d7fc1", BLERead | BLEWrite);
#endif // _BLE_
```

I try to run both next to eachother, and the sketch runs when I define data as the unsignedLongCharacteristic.

```
ifdef _BLE_
    unsigned char rdBuf[RD_BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    i2cRead(device.value(), memory.value(), sizeof(rdBuf), rdBuf);
    data.setValue(rdBuf, RD_BUF_LEN);
#else
    unsigned char rdBuf[4] = { 0 };
    i2cRead(device.value(), memory.value(), sizeof(rdBuf), rdBuf);
    unsigned long output = ((rdBuf[0] << 24) + (rdBuf[1] << 16) + (rdBuf[2] << 8) + (rdBuf[3]));
    data.setValue(output);
#endif // _BLE_
```

Again, the sketch runs fine when I don't define BLE, and it uses the Unsigned long.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that i assigned 0x00 to Data a few lines below what i showed.
now this is fine when you define it as a long, but when the microcontroller expects an array and finds a single value, it crashes